# what is this HTML/CSS element called?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to learn CSS, and I came across this element on a website, when you hover over the paypal icon a drop-box with more information comes up. (the image with the drop-box is below)

I am trying to know the name of this element/property so that I can learn more about it.

Any help will be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvjYj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are referred to as [tooltips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760250(v=vs.85).aspx). The simple way to get this working is by adding a `title` attribute to your target element. Hover example `<img>` element below:

```html
<img src="https://hightechtele.com/media/ht.png" style="cursor:pointer;" title="High Tech Telecom" width="256">
```

Comment: Thanks Ron, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

this element/property is known as "tooltip hover jquery".

you can get it on

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp

Comment: Thanks Manish for sharing the jQuery Example!

Answer (score 0):

It is Bootstrap Popover Plugin.

Here is working example:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
```

[Example link.](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakvaishnav/y6mks0x9/)

and you can also read about this [Here.](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp)

Comment: Thanks Deepak for sharing the bootstrap example.